# Quel est le mot avec le plus de lettres muettes ?

Tags: prononciation, orthographe, demande-de-mot

Le français est réputé pour avoir de nombreuses lettres muettes. Il est fréquent qu'une bonne partie des lettres d'un mot ne soient pas prononcées. On peut penser aux "e" muets à la fin d'un mot ("lettr**e**") ou à l'intérieur d'un mot ("pai**e**ment"), aux consonnes muettes à la fin ("crapau**d**", quasiment tous les pluriels) ou au milieu ("com**p**ter") ou même carrément au début ("**h**ippocampe")... Voire même certaines lettres doubles si on pousse un peu le vice.

On peut facilement trouver des mots avec deux ou trois lettres muettes (par exemple dans "com**p**t**es**"). En existe-t-il avec plus ? Quel est le mot qui en a le plus ?

Comment: On pourrait aussi s'amuser à chercher le mot qui maximise le nombre de lettres par rapport au nombres de syllabes. Par exemple "paiement", huit lettres, deux syllabes...

Comment: Le meilleur rapport lettres/phonèmes est obtenu avec trois mots de cinq lettres qui se prononcent comme une seule voyelle: *aient haies hauts*, sinon *eues* se prononce comme *u* ...

Comment: N'importe quel verbe à la troisième personne du pluriel a au moins trois lettres muettes: _com**p**t**ent**_.

Answer (score 11):

Il y a **huent** qui se prononce *u*, composé donc de 80% de lettres muettes. 
Je pense que pour trouver le mot avec le plus de lettres muettes, mettre un verbe à la 3e personne du pluriel est une bonne stratégie ;)

Answer (score 6):

En utilisant la base [lexique3](https://chrplr.github.io/openlexicon), j'ai fait plusieurs calculs.

Les mots avec le plus de lettres muettes sont : `hauts-commissaires`, `hauts-de-chausses`, `hommes-grenouilles`, `supports-chaussettes` et `moissonneuses-batteuses` avec 9 lettres muettes chacun.

Les mots avec le plus haut ratio de lettres muettes sont : `aient`, `haies`, `hauts` et `huent` (qui ne figure cependant pas dans la base), avec 80% de lettres muettes.

Les résultats détailles sont à voir ci-dessous.

**Nombre de lettres muettes**

J'ai calculé le nombre de lettres muettes en faisant la différence entre le nombre de lettres et le nombre de phonèmes. À noter que pour obtenir le véritable nombre de lettres muettes, il faut retirer le nombre de tirets. J'obtiens :

```
  ortho                   nblettres nbphons ratio letr_muet
   <chr>                       <int>   <int> <dbl>     <int>
 1 hauts-de-chausses              17       6 0.353        11
 2 haut-de-chausses               16       6 0.375        10
 3 hauts-commissaires             18       8 0.444        10
 4 hommes-grenouilles             18       8 0.444        10
 5 supports-chaussettes           20      10 0.5          10
 6 arrière-grands-parents         22      12 0.545        10
 7 moissonneuses-batteuses        23      13 0.565        10
 8 haut-de-chausse                15       6 0.4           9
 9 hauts-fourneaux                15       6 0.4           9
10 saintes-nitouches              17       8 0.471         9
```

**Ratio de lettres muettes**

J'ai aussi calculé le ratio de lettres muettes par rapport au nombre de lettres, et voilà le résultat :

```
   ortho nblettres nbphons ratio letr_muet letr_muet_ratio
   <chr>     <int>   <int> <dbl>     <int>           <dbl>
 1 aient         5       1  0.2          4            0.8 
 2 aient         5       1  0.2          4            0.8 
 3 haies         5       1  0.2          4            0.8 
 4 hauts         5       1  0.2          4            0.8 
 5 hauts         5       1  0.2          4            0.8 
 6 oeufs         5       1  0.2          4            0.8 
 7 aies          4       1  0.25         3            0.75
 8 aies          4       1  0.25         3            0.75
 9 aulx          4       1  0.25         3            0.75
10 eaux          4       1  0.25         3            0.75
```

Pour des mots un peu plus longs :

```
#2 syllabes
   ortho       nblettres nbsyll nbphons ratio letr_muet letr_muet_ratio
   <chr>           <int>  <int>   <int> <dbl>     <int>           <dbl>
 1 hauts-fonds        11      2       3 0.273         8           0.727
 2 huaient             7      2       2 0.286         5           0.714
 3 haussaient         10      2       3 0.3           7           0.7  
 4 hachaient           9      2       3 0.333         6           0.667
 5 hantaient           9      2       3 0.333         6           0.667
 6 happaient           9      2       3 0.333         6           0.667
 7 haut-fond           9      2       3 0.333         6           0.667
 8 hi-han              6      2       2 0.333         4           0.667
 9 hi-han              6      2       2 0.333         4           0.667
10 hissaient           9      2       3 0.333         6           0.667

#3 syllabes
   ortho             nblettres nbsyll nbphons ratio letr_muet letr_muet_ratio
   <chr>                 <int>  <int>   <int> <dbl>     <int>           <dbl>
 1 hauts-de-chausses        17      3       6 0.353        11           0.647
 2 haut-de-chausses         16      3       6 0.375        10           0.625
 3 accueillaient            13      3       5 0.385         8           0.615
 4 effeuillaient            13      3       5 0.385         8           0.615
 5 haut-de-chausse          15      3       6 0.4           9           0.6  
 6 hauts-fourneaux          15      3       6 0.4           9           0.6  
 7 haïssaient               10      3       4 0.4           6           0.6  
 8 accouchaient             12      3       5 0.417         7           0.583
 9 accourraient             12      3       5 0.417         7           0.583
10 accueillants             12      3       5 0.417         7           0.583
```

Comment: Combien de lettres a **œufs** ;-)

Comment: ahah oui la base n'est pas parfaite !

Comment: Est-ce qu'on peut réellement considérer qu'il y a des lettres muettes (et combien ?) dans les sons "ch", "au", "usse" et "ill" ?

Answer (score 5):

#### Phonèmes vs. lettres

En suivant la recette offerte par [Flying_whale](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/29414/13100), on pourrait aussi penser au verbe, assez rare, [houer](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/houer), dont la 3<sup>e</sup> personne du pluriel à l’indicatif présent se prononce simplement *[u]* :

- ils houent

On pourra argumenter que deux lettres contribuent à créer ce son, et donc que le taux de lettres muettes n’est que de 67%, mais le ratio du nombre de phonèmes au nombre de lettres, lui, serait de 1 sur 6, et donc aussi 5 lettres de plus que le nombre de phonèmes.

En augmentant le nombres de phonèmes prononcés, on trouvera facilement des exemples où la perte est plus grande :

- **hausseraient** (pour 4 phonèmes, 8 lettres de plus)
- **chausseraient** (pour 5 phonèmes, 8 lettres de plus)